# node routing to html file

Tags: node.js, express, routes

This is my folder structure:

```
root
   admin
      index.html
      bootstrap.css
      ...
      ...
app.js
```

when I'm running

```
node app.js
```

using Express 4, routing works correctly but I don't know how to view this file:

```
http://localhost/admin/index.html
```

it seems like it searching for this route...

so I tried to render the file to the client and it works but then all its css and script doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell since you didn't post any code.  But my guess is that you aren't serving your static files.  check the app.use static middleware in the express documentation to see how to serve css/js files.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at:

http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

And use:

```
app.use(express.static('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Express is a framework and provide the template structure, so it's good to put the files of frontend in the folder views, not in static. Static is more used for import libs, js, css.
In you case, put the index.html in the views folder, and the route can be somethink this:

```
res.sendFile("index.html");
```

[Docs](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html#res.sendFile)